# Create child only if the parent has active class in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements, parent-child, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to create a span in angularJS using ng-if based on the condition that the parent element has 'active' class.

I'm not sure how do I achieve this.

Here's my code:

```
<li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='{{$index}}' ng-repeat="obj in myData | limitTo:4" ng-class='{active:$first}'>
    <span ng-if="if parent li is active()"></span>
    <img ng-src="{{obj.source}} />
</li>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like the below code, also you can check this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/2y1vxdge/1/) for your example.

Templates:

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in myData" ng-click="select($index)" ng-class="{active: $index == selected}">
     {{obj.value}}
     <span ng-if="$index==selected">*</span>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.selected = 0;
$scope.select= function(index) {
   $scope.selected = index; 
};
```